# javascript websocket clients

Tags: javascript, websocket

Can a single html page, with embedded javascript, have more then a single websocket client ??
Or is it one socket per javascript thread ? I can't seem to find any documentation on
this so I figured I'd ask the group.

Comment: This seems like it would be trivial to test for yourself.

Comment: please do not add signatures to your posts: [faq#signatures]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, there is a limit for Firefox.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=664305)  WebSockets are *globally* (across all open pages) limited to 200 concurrent connections.

Chrome does not [appear](http://blog.dennis-boldt.de/?p=177) to currently have a limit, but they're refactoring the WebSocket code and it looks like [they'll be adding a limit of 30 connections per "group"](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118268#c3), which I assume means 30 connections per Origin.

Answer (score 0):

Make as many as you need:

```
var Socket = new WebSocket(url);
```